# Adding stock price data frames to a list so you have a list of stock prices histories

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the historical stock price data for all these tickers going back to 2014. All of these companies went public in 2014, so it will automatically get them from the day they first traded.

What I would like is for the `stocklist` list to contain at the end is a list of dataframes/price histories for each company, but separately and not put together.

So stocklist would be data frames/stock histories for each company, i.e. `['LC', 'ZAYO']` etc.

```
tickers = ['LC', 'ZAYO', 'GPRO', 'ANET', 'GRUB', 'CSLT', 'ONDK', 'QUOT', 'NEWR', 'ATEN']
stocklist = []

for i in tickers:
    stock = Share(i)
    adj = stock.get_historical('2014-1-1', '2016-12-27')
    df = pd.DataFrame(adj)
    df = df.set_index('Date')
    df['Adj_Close'] = df['Adj_Close'].astype(float, errors='coerce')
    price = df.sort()

i = price
stocklist.append(i)
```

Comment: fix your indentation and your code may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not appending to `stocklist` inside the loop due to bad indentation.

Also, you're messing with the loop variable `i` needlessly.

This might work, although it's difficult to test since the `Share` class is not available:

```
tickers = ['LC', 'ZAYO', 'GPRO', 'ANET', 'GRUB',
           'CSLT', 'ONDK', 'QUOT', 'NEWR', 'ATEN']
stocklist = []

for ticker in tickers:
    stock = Share(ticker)
    adj = stock.get_historical('2014-1-1', '2016-12-27')
    df = pd.DataFrame(adj)
    df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    df['Adj_Close'] = df['Adj_Close'].astype(float, errors='coerce')
    df.sort_index(inplace=True)
    stocklist.append(df)
```

Changes I made:

- use `tickers` as a variable name instead of `list` which is the name of a built-in type
- set index and sort the dataframe in-place instead of making copies
- use `DataFrame.sort_index()` for sorting since `DataFrame.sort()` is deprecated
- fixed indentation so `stocklist` is populated inside the loop
- removed the unnecessary assignment before `stocklist` appending

It might also be more useful to collect the dataframes in a dictionary keyed by tickers. So you would initialize `stocklist = {}` and instead of appending do `stocklist[ticker] = df`.

Comment: Great, thanks so much. Actually stocklist[ticker] = df is much more in line with what I was tying to do. What I'd really like to do is have the Adj Close for all put in one dataframe. That way I could 1. plot all prices on one graf and 2. see what the price change since IPO was for each. I'm still not able to figure that out so any pointers would help!